iOS limited login - FBSDKs
I'm using react-native-fbsdk-sdk for facebook login in my application. I just received email from Meta about upgrade FBSDKs to latest version (v17.0.0) to incorporate "Privacy Manifest" for Apple Store submission. So here is my update:
react-native-fbsdk-sdk : ^12.1.3 → ^13.0.0
 Bug Report
After upgrade to new version. I get two bugs:
iOS limited login
I've followed the document to apply in my code
try {
await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(
['public_profile', 'email'],
'limited',
'my_nonce'
);

if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
const result = await AuthenticationToken.getAuthenticationTokenIOS();
if (result?.authenticationToken)
loginSocial(result.authenticationToken, LoginProvider.FACEBOOK);
} else {
const result = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
if (result) loginSocial(result.accessToken, LoginProvider.FACEBOOK);
}

But in the facebook login screen, a warning appears with the following content. How can I hide them for my users?

Can't fetch profile by authenticationToken
I can't use token return from method AuthenticationToken.getAuthenticationTokenIOS() to fetch user profile. I have log and still receive the token
To Reproduce
Upgrade or install version 13.0.0
Expected Behavior
Don't display warning content in facebook login view
Can fetch profile
Code Example
...

 const pressFb = async () => {
    try {
      await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(
        ['public_profile', 'email'],
        'limited',
        'my_nonce'
      );
      if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        const result = await AuthenticationToken.getAuthenticationTokenIOS();
        if (result?.authenticationToken)
          loginSocial(result.authenticationToken, LoginProvider.FACEBOOK);
      } else {
        const result = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if (result) loginSocial(result.accessToken, LoginProvider.FACEBOOK);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      onClose();
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  };
...

<Button.Primary label={translate('auth.continueWithFacebook')} outline leftIcon={'IC_FB'} style={BTN_LOGIN} labelStyle={TXT_BTN} onPress={pressFb} /> 
...

Environment
System:

OS: macOS 14.2.1
CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
Memory: 106.08 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh

Binaries:

Node: 18.18.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.0/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
npm: 9.8.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.0/bin/npm
Watchman: 2024.03.18.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman

Managers:

CocoaPods: 1.12.0 - /Users/drake/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/bin/pod

SDKs:

iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 23.2, iOS 17.2, macOS 14.2, tvOS 17.2, watchOS 10.2
Android SDK: Not Found

IDEs:

Android Studio: 2022.1 AI-221.6008.13.2211.9477386
Xcode: 15.1/15C65 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild

Languages:
Java: 17.0.10 - /usr/bin/javac

npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
react-native: 0.71.3 => 0.71.3
react-native-macos: Not Found


Did you manage to solve this yet?

I also had the warning issue, but then I noticed that it only shows up on users that have an App Role. Have you tried with a production user? About your second issue, are you getting an authentication token? If not, your issue is very similar with mine here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78499305/facebook-limited-login-on-ios-doesnt-work-for-production-users

Hi. I had to roll back to an older version for it to work. I have not been able to find a solution to the current problem
