Facebook Limited Login on iOS doesn't work for production users
Firstly, it's been a while since I've published a Facebook app to support Facebook Login and I'm not sure whether the status Published is the same as Live, can anyone confirm that?
I recently updated Facebook Login to Facebook Limited Login (Facebook SDK v.17.0.1). Prior to this update, the classic Facebook Login was working fine in dev mode.
My issue is that I can't login, because I either don't receive a AuthenticationToken or that I receive a status cancelled (I'm testing on iOS 17.4.1).
The flow is as follows:
I'm creating a LoginConfiguration instance with a SHA256 nonce as below:
let rawNonce = String.randomNonceString()
let sha256Nonce = rawNonce.sha256
let config = LoginConfiguration(permissions: ["public_profile", "email"], tracking: .enabled, nonce: sha256Nonce)!

Once I have the config I'm using it to login, and I'm accessing the token from the AuthenticationToken.current as per the Limited Login docs here.
let loginManager = FacebookLogin.LoginManager()
loginManager.logIn(viewController: viewController, configuration: configuration) { result in
    switch result {
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let token):
            let authTokenString = AuthenticationToken.current?.tokenString
            // Create OAuth credential for Firebase Auth using the authTokenString and rawNonce

        case .cancelled:
            // User cancelled login

        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
    }
}

I have identified the following issues:

With a user that has an App Role in the Facebook app, everything works great.
With a production user that doesn't have an App Role in the Facebook app, the login fails with 2 different scenarios:

Scenario A:
If I pass tracking .enabled on the LoginConfiguration instance then the login function returns result .success, but the AuthenticationToken.current is nil.
Scenario B:
If I pass tracking .limited on the LoginConfiguration instance then the login function returns result .cancelled which makes no sense.
Other things I tried:

I have tried enabling App Tracking Transparency prior to logging in, but the above behaviour remained the same.
According to Facebook's Limited Login docs I understand that I shouldn't be using the AccessToken returned in the login's callback anymore, and I should use the global AuthenticationToken (and also the Profile to directly receive user's name, email, etc). However, I have tried creating the Firebase Auth credential with the AccessToken that's returned in the login's callback, but Firebase Auth sign in failed with the error Bad access token.
I tried accessing the AuthenticationToken every 0.5 sec until it's not nil, but this didn't work either.
I tried on both the Simulator and a real device.

UPDATE
The functions for the random nonce string and SHA256 are the following:
public extension String {
    
    static func randomNonceString(length: Int = 32) -> String {
        precondition(length > 0)
        var randomBytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: length)
        let errorCode = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, randomBytes.count, &randomBytes)
        if errorCode != errSecSuccess {
            fatalError(
                "Unable to generate nonce. OSStatus \(errorCode)"
            )
        }
        
        let charset: [Character] = Array("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._")
        
        let nonce = randomBytes.map { byte in
            charset[Int(byte) % charset.count]
        }
        
        return String(nonce)
    }
    
    var sha256: String {
        let inputData = Data(self.utf8)
        let hashedData = SHA256.hash(data: inputData)
        let hashString = hashedData.compactMap { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
        return hashString
    }
}

Tried again today (03/07/2024) without changing anything in my codebase and it worked. So I'll assume that this was something with Facebook's BE when they originally released Limited Login. For reference, here's the issue on Github https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/2387

I could not reproduce your issue, in fact I actually got my own code running with the help of your example. One thing caught my attention though, because I've been there. In your "Other things I tried" paragraph, you mention that you got a "bad access token" from Firebase. Are you sure you sent the rawNonce as part of the OAuthProvider.credential()? Could you post the whole error? Also your sha256 hash function might be interesting to see, maybe the format doesn't match Firebase's expectations. I followed the same guidelines that you mentioned in that paragraph and it works for me.

same Issue here idk what to do !!

@Jerrot thanks for the comment, I've updated my question with the functions. However, as of today it seems it works for me too.

@artur-marchetto maybe it's worth it giving it another try.
